# drupal 7 entity and simple test

Tags: entities, testing

What I can't workout is what steps I need to see if the entity is loaded using simple test. Any direction will be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Definition of creation of a entity.
 */

/**
 * Coded entity display test.
 */
class CreateCoded extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  /**
   * Implements getInfo().
   */
  public static function getInfo() {
    return array(
      'name' => 'Coded',
      'description' => 'Adding table to entities to create entity',
      'group' => 'Coded',
    );
  }

  /**
   * Enables modules that are need for test.
   */
  public function setUp() {
    // Enable any module that you will need in your tests.
    parent::setUp('coded');
  }

  /**
   * Tests for table coded. 
   * 
   * @Description
   *   Method needs to start with test if you wnat to test.
   */
  public function testCreateCodedEntity() {
    // how to I test the entity

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples):

> This project aims to provide high-quality, well-documented API
>   examples for a broad range of Drupal core functionality.
>
> The Examples project contains many modules which hopefully illustrate
>   best practices for implementing various Drupal APIs. These modules can
>   be enabled individually, and will typically add menu items to your
>   site, which should guide you through their features. You can then look
>   through the code to see what they are doing.

It has a drupal 7 & 8 [entity example](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/tree/HEAD:/entity_example) in which has a [test](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/HEAD:/entity_example/entity_example.test) as well.